# Astroid slope as a function of x, y

Tags: derivatives, curves, tangent-line

I'm trying to find the slope of an astroid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid

Using $x = a\sin^3(t)$ and $y = a\cos^3(t)$, $dy(t)/dx(t) = -\tan(t)$. I expect $\tan(t) = y/x$, giving $dy/dx (x, y) = -y/x$, but this differs from the answer from implicit differentiation of $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = a^{2/3}$, which is $dy/dx(x, y) = -y^{1/3}/x^{1/3}$. Why is this? Is my expression for $\tan(t)$ wrong?

Comment: Use implicit differentiation on $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = a^{2/3}$ and simple algebra.

Comment: Wouldn't $\frac{dy(t)}{dx(t)}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{ -a\sin{(t)}\cos^2{(t)}}{a\cos{(t)}\sin^2{(t)}}=\frac{-\tan{(t)}}{\tan^2{(t)}}=\frac{-1}{\tan{(t)}}$?

Comment: And moreover $\frac{-1}{\tan t} = - \frac{\cos t}{\sin t} = - \frac{y^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}}$

Comment: Teamwork, I like it.

Comment: I will add that you did do the implicit differentiation correctly though, @ttshaw1 just so you know :).